# Security cam working out side IP but not open on local IP

Tags: networking, dvr

I need some help in my DVR configuration with my router. My dvr brand is H.264. 
I assigned IP to dvr as (194.168.1.121) and in router DMS host put this IP (194.168.1.121).
DNS server enabled and in dynamic DNS inserted the host name mycam.dyndns.tv and my dyndns username and password

Then in virtual server option I insert application name as DVR- exrnal port start 8080 and end 8080 server IP is my dvr IP (194.168.1.121)

It is working outside at every IP, but not open on local IP or this router.

Can someone let me know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the chosen local IP address is in the correct range for your router? I.e. your router is also 194.168.1.xxx? If so, have you checked your subnet settings?

A work-around is to access the cam locally through the global/WAN IP or host name, i.e. going through the back door - walk around the house - and come back in through the front :)